# Upgrade Elastic Search from v7.13.0 to v7.17.0 in Heroku

Tags: elasticsearch, heroku

I'm not able to upgrade Elastic Search in Heroku because apparantelly it changes the zone_count parameter.

Following the warnings seems to not be working as it asks me to signup to change the zones_count and the link given redirects to a 404 page.

Has anyone gone through this before? Screenshots below:

[image: Upgrading from v7.13.0 t v 7.17.0]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance